# How to get the column header or field name in Ag Grid when row cell is clicked?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I'm trying to get the `headerName` or column field name of the row cell clicked in Ag Grid.

[This](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/column-properties/#reference-header-headerName) is the ag-grid document for `headerName` but I don't see how to access this value during any grid event?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the document [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/column-properties/#reference-events-onCellClicked), Ag-grid has a callback `onCellClicked(event)`, in that callback you can access `event.colDef.headerName` or `event.colDef.field`